# Creating Markers and Problems in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, compilation, eclipse-plugin

I have been doing a fair amount of research but am having a hard time understanding the relation between IProblem and IMarker. I have been able to create problems and add markers but the two do not seem to be connected. Are problems and markers independent? At first I was thinking that if I add problems to ReconcileContext the markers would appear automatically but that does not appear to be the case. Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong?

SecureCompilationParticipant.java:

```
    public class SecureCompilationParticipant extends CompilationParticipant {

    public boolean isActive(IJavaProject project) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconcile(ReconcileContext context) {
        // Call Parent
        super.reconcile(context);

        // Used in expression loop
        int start, end, line;
        String fileName;

        // Check to see if content has changed
        IJavaElementDelta elementDelta = context.getDelta();
        IJavaElement element = elementDelta.getElement();
        if((elementDelta.getFlags() & IJavaElementDelta.F_CONTENT) != 0) {
            System.out.printf("The content of %s has changed%n",
                    element.getElementName());
            try {
                CompilationUnit compilation = context.getAST8();
                NodeVisitor visitor = new NodeVisitor();
                compilation.accept(visitor);

                // Iterate through expressions
                for (ExpressionStatement expressionStatement : visitor.getExpressionStatements()) {
                    start = expressionStatement.getStartPosition();
                    end = start + expressionStatement.getLength();
                    line = compilation.getLineNumber(start - 1);
                    fileName = element.getElementName();
                    System.out.printf("Expression: %s%n", expressionStatement.getExpression().toString());

                    CategorizedProblem[] problems = new CategorizedProblem[0];
                    ArrayList<CategorizedProblem> problemList = new ArrayList<CategorizedProblem>();

                    // Put problems
                    SecureCodingProblem problem = new SecureCodingProblem(fileName);
                    problem.setSourceStart(start);
                    problem.setSourceEnd(end);
                    problem.setSourceLineNumber(line);
                    problemList.add(problem);
                    context.putProblems(IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER, problemList.toArray(problems));

                    // Create marker
                    IResource resource = element.getUnderlyingResource();
                    IMarker marker = resource.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
                    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "This is a test marker");
                    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_WARNING);
                    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line);
                    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LOCATION, String.format("Line %d", line));
                }
            } catch (JavaModelException e) {
                // From CompilationUnit compilation = context.getAST8();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                // From IMarker marker = resource.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

SecureCodingProblem.java:

```
public class SecureCodingProblem extends CategorizedProblem {

    private int m_sourceStart;
    private int m_sourceEnd;
    private int m_sourceLineNumber;
    private char[] m_fileName;

    public SecureCodingProblem(String fileName) {
        m_fileName = fileName.toCharArray();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getArguments() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "This is a problem";
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getOriginatingFileName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return m_fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceEnd() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return m_sourceEnd;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceLineNumber() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return m_sourceLineNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return m_sourceStart;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isError() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWarning() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSourceEnd(int sourceEnd) {
        m_sourceEnd = sourceEnd;

    }

    @Override
    public void setSourceLineNumber(int lineNumber) {
        m_sourceLineNumber = lineNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSourceStart(int sourceStart) {
        m_sourceStart = sourceStart;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCategoryID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return CategorizedProblem.CAT_CODE_STYLE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMarkerType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IProblem` is specific to the Java Development Tools whereas `IMarker` can be used for any file in the workspace.

The JavaDoc for `IProblem` says:

> Note: the compiler produces IProblems internally, which are turned
>   into markers by the JavaBuilder so as to persist problem descriptions.
>   This explains why there is no API allowing to reach IProblem detected 
>   when compiling. However, the Java problem markers carry equivalent
>   information to IProblem, in particular their ID (attribute "id") is
>   set to one of the IDs defined on this interface.